# If $\{v_k:k\in\mathbb N\}$ is a dense subset of $H$, why does there exist a subsequence $\{v_{k_j}:1\leq j\leq n\}$ that is L.I for all $n$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I'm reading through a proof that if $H$ is a separable Hilbert Space, then $H$ has an orthonormal basis. It starts by saying that $H$ contains a countable dense subset $\{v_k:k\in\mathbb N\}$, and then says that there exists a subsequence $\{v_{k_j}:1\leq j\leq n\}$ that is linearly independent for every $n$. They don't explain why such a subsequence exists so could somebody explain why? Also, what is the difference between between $\{v_{k_j}:1\leq j\leq n\}$ being linearly independent  for every $n$ and $\{v_{k_j}:j\in\mathbb N\}$ being a linearly independent set?

Comment: To your second question, there is no difference as you suspect. My guess is that they phrase it in terms of finite sets of increasing cardinality because the justification is by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are working under the hypothesis $\dim H=\infty$, otherwise the statement is obviously false.

If there's $n$ such that there's no linearly independent subset of $\{v_k\}_k$ with cardinality $n$, then there exists $v_{k_1},\dots,v_{k_{m}}\in\{v_k\}_k$, $m<n$, such that $\langle v_k,k\in\mathbb{N}\rangle=\langle v_{k_1},\dots,v_{k_{m}}\rangle$ is finite dimensional, therefore closed. This implies $H$ is finite dimensional, as $\{v_k\}_k$ is dense in $H$. In fact,
$$
H=\overline{\langle v_k,k\in\mathbb{N}\rangle}=\overline{\langle v_{k_1},\dots,v_{k_{m}}\rangle}=\langle v_{k_1},\dots,v_{k_{m}}\rangle.
$$

As for your last question, to say that $\{ v_{k_j};j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is linearly independent is to say that for every $n$ and for every choice of $n$ elements in it, we have a linearly independent set. Assuming that for every $n$ there's a subset of $n$ linearly independent vectors, you can construct such an infinite set. So the statements are equivalent.